# Eclipse Plug-in Development - Instantiate Java Editor Programmatically

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I'm developing an eclipse plugin and I need to, programmatically, instantiate a Java Editor.
It goes like this. I want to creat a new MultiPageEditor that opens Java files and shows the Java file in the first tab and some transformations in the second and third tab (in some specific languages).
I don't wan't to re-write Java Editor, so I want to call Eclipse's Java Editr programmatically.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thnaks a lot.

Marcos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!
I had to instantiate CompilationUnitEditor.

Hope this is usefull to someone.

Thanks!